# search markers with leaflet search

Tags: search, leaflet, markers

I´m trying to use leaftlet search but it doesnt find the markers.
The markers are populated on the map as it should be, but the search wont work.
I have a **freg.js** file where I have the information to create markers, and I want to search using propertie "**maclora**" for example:

```
     var freg_palmela = {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "name": "freg_palmela",
      "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": 
      "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
      "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "maclora": 
"0004A30B00FB82F0", "serial_num": "2,02103E+14", "freguesias": 
"Freguesia de PALMELA", "model": "OCTANS 40", "latitude": 
"38.569244417", "longitude": "-8.88123655", "pt": 
"PT1508D2052900", "instalation_date": "11/04/2022", "last_ul": 
"21/06/2022 05:55", "last_jr": "20/06/2022 21:13", "last_ja": 
"20/06/2022 21:13", "last_rssi": "-109", "last_snr": "5,8", 
"jr_rssi": "-111,52", "jr_snr": "0,09", "Issue": "Ok" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.88123655, 
38.569244417 ] } },
```

On the .html file the code I have there is

```
var fregData = L.geoJSON(freg_palmela, {
style: function (feature) {
return feature.properties.style;
},

 onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

 layer.bindPopup('<b>MacloRa: ' +
          feature.properties.maclora +
          '<br>Serial Number: ' +
          '<small>' +
          feature.properties.serial_num +
          '<br>Model: ' +
          feature.properties.model +
          '<br>Last UL: ' +
          +feature.properties.last_ul +
          '<br>Last JR: ' +
          feature.properties.last_jr +
          '<br>Last JA ' +
          feature.properties.last_ja
          );
layer.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
ev.target.openPopup();
});
layer.on('mouseout',function(ev) {
ev.target.closePopup();
});

}
}).addTo(map);


  var overlays = {
    "Palmela":fregData
   };

L.control.search({
layer: fregData,
initial: false,
propertyName: 'maclora',
buildTip: function(text, val) {
    var type = val.layer.feature.properties.maclora;
    return '<a href="#" class="'+type+'">'+text+'<b>'+type+'</b> 
</a>';
}
})
.addTo(map);
```

[image: Search not finding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you're using [leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search).

The problem is in the referenced layer option. It should point to the geojson variable. In short, `layer: overlays,` should be `layer: fregData,`.

For a working example - based on the provided code -, please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nfxsj6g/).

---

**Update**: example with data in separate js file

*What I did*:

1. I put the two files below (`data.js` and `index.html`) in a folder (`my-map`).
2. Navigated to the folder on my commandline (`cd my-map`)
3. Ran a local webserver (e.g `php -S localhost:3456`).

*What I see*:
When I visit localhost:3456 in my browser, the page loads without errors. If I type '00' in the search widget, the feature with number '0004A30B00FB82F0' is found. On click the marker is highlighted with a red circle (as demonstrated in the fiddle above).

`data.js` file:

```js
var freg_palmela = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "freg_palmela",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name", "properties": {
            "name":
                "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature", "properties": {
                "maclora": "0004A30B00FB82F0", "serial_num": "2,02103E+14",
                "freguesias": "Freguesia de PALMELA", "model": "OCTANS 40",
                "latitude": "38.569244417", "longitude": "-8.88123655",
                "pt": "PT1508D2052900", "instalation_date": "11/04/2022",
                "last_ul": "21/06/2022 05:55", "last_jr": "20/06/2022 21:13",
                "last_ja": "20/06/2022 21:13", "last_rssi": "-109",
                "last_snr": "5,8", "jr_rssi": "-111,52",
                "jr_snr": "0,09", "Issue": "Ok"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-8.88123655, 38.569244417]
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

`index.html` file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-search@3.0.2/dist/leaflet-search.min.css">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 280px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-search@3.0.2/dist/leaflet-search.src.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([38.6, -8.9], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
    }).addTo(map);

    var fregData = L.geoJSON(freg_palmela, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('<b>MacloRa: ' +
                feature.properties.maclora +
                '<br>Serial Number: ' +
                '<small>' +
                feature.properties.serial_num +
                '<br>Model: ' +
                feature.properties.model +
                '<br>Last UL: ' +
                +feature.properties.last_ul +
                '<br>Last JR: ' +
                feature.properties.last_jr +
                '<br>Last JA ' +
                feature.properties.last_ja
            );
            layer.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
                ev.target.openPopup();
            });
            layer.on('mouseout',function(ev) {
                ev.target.closePopup();
            });

        }
    }).addTo(map);

    L.control.search({
        layer: fregData,
        initial: false,
        propertyName: 'maclora',
        buildTip: function(text, val) {
            var type = val.layer.feature.properties.maclora;
            return '<a href="#" class="' + type + '">' + text + '<b>' + type + '</b></a>';
        }
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Sidney, It does work if the var freg_palmela ={....} is in the .html file like you said, but if I get the var fregData = L.geoJSON(freg_palmela).addTo(map); from .js file it doesn´t find anything. That´s what I can´t figure out.

Comment: hi @Bruno, thanks for your reaction. Can you please update your question with more info and what you're trying to accomplish? So, an example of the HTML and the JS file you're working with + any error messages you're encountering in your browser dev tools. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sidney, I have updated the question with code and image of what I can do. The search, if the information that I have in the freg.js file is in the index.html does work. But If I retrieve it from freg.js the search doesn´t work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Bruno, thanks for the update. I will have a look at it. Before I do that, one question: are you seeing any error messages in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Hi @Sidney, that´s the thing, it doesn´t give me any error... and exports ok

Comment: hi @Bruno, updated my answer with an example with data in separate js file.

Comment: Hi @Sidney. Brilliant! That´s it no doubt. Thanks a lot for the help. Some things I still haven´t figure out. Like styling markers according to a feature.property. I guess I´m on a leaning path (very steep one :)  )